# Netbeans bring one JButton in front of another

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

I have a grid of `JButton` controls - to this I want to add other buttons which are larger on top (representing houses) but these are always placed behind the smaller buttons making up the grid.

Due to other complications in the program, I cannot just make these buttons invisible when these larger buttons are added, and then visible again when these are deleted.

Is there a way to but the larger buttons representing houses, on top of the smaller grid buttons so I can avoid making these invisible/visible?

Comment: Show the code you've tried.

Comment: *"but these are always placed behind the smaller buttons"* 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.